# Как такая реализация ЧПУ влияет на скорость сайта?

Tags: mod_rewrite, php, чпу

Хотел сделать так. Из этого:

```
http://localhost/site/f2.php?fa=5
```

получить

```
http://localhost/site/red   (т.е. red имеет fa=5 )
```

Обычным способом через регулярные выражения у меня не выходит и я сделал извращенно:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule red f2.php?fa=5
RewriteRule blue f2.php?fa=6
RewriteRule white f2.php?fa=2 (и т.д. у меня может получиться сотни таких строк)
..........
```

Я понимаю, что это дурдом и так никто не делает... но если это работает и если на скорость сайта не влияет то почему нет.. хотел узнать, если у меня таких строк в htaccess будет примерно 500 штук, это повлияет на скорость сайта или еще как-нибудь?

Мне просто очень надо, чтобы человек мог набрать короткий адрес в адресной строке и найти то, что надо ему... и еще я понимаю, что если он будет обычным образом щелкать, то все равно в адр. строке будет писаться   `http://localhost/site/f2.php?fa=5`... ну и пусть, зато может ввести покороче и попасть туда же... что вы об этом думаете? спасибо!`введите код здесь`

Comment: если решите оставить так как есть (а вы наверняка так и сделаете поначалу) обязательно добавьте флаг [L]  в каждой строчке RewriteRule red f2.php?fa=5[L] Тогда программа будет прекращать поиск после совпадения. Сейчас у вас все строчки перебираются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я делаю так, и основным входом у меня index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

url можно разбить через explode, в вашем случае http://localhost/site/red, догадываюсь что нужно вытащить с базы какие-то данные по условию где столбец таблицы имеет значение red, то набросав код можно получить такое, url останется красивым, и не надо 100500 записей в .htaccess, вот примерно как это выглядит

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['route']))
    {
        $exp = explode($_GET['route'], '/')
        if($exp[0] == 'site')
        {
            $sql = mysql_query("select * from `table` where `name` = '". $exp[1] ."'") or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
            {
                echo $row['id'].$row['value'];
            }
        }
    }
?>

?>
```

Comment: @johniek_comp, cпасибо... но кое что мне непонятно) я пишу так:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ f2.php?fa=$1 [L,QSA]

код не работает... можете уточнить что это за переменные: name,id и value (route это fa  я понимаю, table это таблица откуда берутся все мои данные). спасибо!